# forward shift surjective mapping or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a question regarding shift operators.

Given an infinite dimensional seperable Hilbertspace $H$ and a shift operator defined on the span of an ONB $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by:

$Se_n=e_{n+1}$

By the continuation theorem of bounded operators on dense subspaces (or by defining $S$ on $H$ in terms of fourier series) we can extend $S$ to a bounded operator from $H$ in itself.

Clearly $S$ is not surjective as a mapping defined on the span of the ONB. My question is: Is it always the case, that the (unique) continuation on H remains non surjective? If so or if not, why?

More generally, does the answer to this question still hold for (bounded) weighted shift operators of this form?

thanks in advance

Comment: Since you seem to know that the continuation on H is unique, by "Is it *always* the case" do you mean "for *any* bounded operator $T$ defined on a dense subspace $K\subset H$, and not surjective"? And do you mean not surjective from $K$ to $H,$ or do you assume $T(K)\subsetneq K$?

Comment: If the weights tend to $0,$ the weighted shift would extend uniquely to a compact operator. So besides the orthogonality of the range to $e_1,$ the other reason for nonsurjectivity would be compactness.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H_0 = (\operatorname{span}\{e_1\})^\perp$. Note that since $H_0$ is a closed subset of $H$ and $S(\sum_{i =1}^n a_i e_i) \in H_0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{K}$, we have that the unique bounded extension of $S$ is also valued in $H_0$ and hence is non-surjective.

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't take into consideration that $H_0$ is closed. That way it works out.